# I cant seem to get it straight with my search. Issues of strings and array are on my case

Tags: javascript

Here is my script for displaying loading data onto my table:

```
function my_data(result,j){
    console.log(result);
            
    var length = result.length;
    console.log(length);
            
    j = Number(j);
    $('#news_data tbody').empty();
            
    for(var i = 0 ; i < length; i++){
        j+=1;
        var tr = "<tr>";
        tr += "<td>"+ j +"</td>";
        tr += "<td><a href='"+ result[i].product_id +"'  target='_blank'>"
              +result[i].product_name +"</a></td>";
        tr += "<td>"+ result[i].product_price +"</td>";
        tr += "</tr>";
        $('#news_data tbody').append(tr);
    }
}
```

And here is my search:

```
$('#search_text').keyup(function () {
    var search = $(this).val();
    if (search != '') {
        my_data(search);
    } else {
        my_data();
    }
});
```

When I search I get the list of items filtered as undefined

Comment: You are not passing in `j`.  `Number(undefined) === NaN`

Comment: Kindly post how it should be.

Comment: Either pass it in, or default it to 0, or 1.  Whatever the default starting j should be